# i want create a size chart image popup with cancel(X) button on my product page in magento 1.7?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

Currently it's opening in separate tab as an image file when i click on size chart on product page.

**SIZE CHART**

Comment: If you do not want to use ready made functionality and you think that some one write code for you here then it is not possible.

Comment: Why are you so rude? who asked. don't answer if u don't want to.

Comment: I have provide you ready made extension link and you vote down. If you do not want  solution then why you are asking here. This extension will work. If you do not want to use then don't use. But this will satisfy your requirement. Still you down vote.